# Doubt in Euler theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I didn't understand what Fulton says in the beginning of his book about the formal derivatives:

[image]

Counterexample: $F=X_1^3X_2^2+X_3^5$

Since $X_1(3X_1^2X_2^2)+X_2(2X_1^3X_2)+X_3(5X_3^4)\neq 5F$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you pulling our collective leg?

Comment: @user1 I didn't understand your point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Counterexample for your counterexample:
$$X_1(3X_1^2X_2^2)+X_2(2X^3_1X_2)+X_3(5X^4_3)=5F.$$

Comment: I wanted to find a counterexample to your counterexample for your counterexample, but apparently, your answer is correct.

Comment: but $5F=5X_1^3X_2^2+5X_3^5$

Comment: ha yes, ok, really stupid question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Looks like the sequence of counterexamples stops here!

Answer (score 2):

You miscalculated. It actually is $5F$.

Comment: You beat me to it.